# MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012) kernel panics after attaching Thunderbolt dock

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, thunderbolt, dock, kernel-panic

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012) running OS X 10.11.6 that I wish to use with one of two brand new OWC Thunderbolt docks.  I have a newer laptop, MacBook Pro (2017, two Thunderbolt ports), which works fine with both docks after updating the OS to Big Sur.  The odd behavior before the OS update on one laptop with USB-C and the kernel panic on the other leads me to believe the hardware is just fine, it's the software that is out of sorts.

I am able to use Thunderbolt peripherals fine with the older laptop, these include an Apple FireWire adapter, an Apple Ethernet adapter, and a Kanex dual port Ethernet and USB 3.0 adapter.  I can plug the one OWC dock into the older laptop with a USB cable to use it as a USB-C hub without a kernel panic, and maybe that is the best I can hope for.  It is a Thunderbolt device though and so should be able to plug in to a Thunderbolt port without causing a kernel panic.  It's the weekend now and so I'm not getting OWC technical support at the moment.  Even if or when I do get a hold of OWC I would not be surprised if their reply is that this is not a supported configuration and so I'm on my own.  The plan is to get a Thunderbolt dock working on this older laptop so I can get some more use out of it before it's just too old to keep going.

I'm hoping someone ran into this before and knows of a fix.  Searching for fixes is difficult given the age of the computer as more recent Thunderbolt discussions hide anything useful, assuming that there is anything useful to find.  Using a Thunderbolt 2 host with a Thunderbolt 4 dock is not likely to be a common mix of hardware.  I'm hoping that there is a software fix for me out there.  I could keep experimenting but since a failure means a kernel panic that is slow work and runs the risk of damaging my OS install.

Comment: The 2012 isn't supposed to be able to run Big Sur. Roll it back to Catalina & see what happens.

Comment: Big Sur was installed on the 2017 MacBook Pro, not the 2012 MacBook Pro.  I'm having trouble updating the OS on the 2012 laptop because of how the drive was formatted.  I'll update the 2012 laptop OS once I figure out what I did wrong with the drive.  The 2017 laptop didn't like the new docks until I updated to Big Sur, now it likes the docks just fine.

Comment: Then can you add correct & pertinent information to your question. You're talking about two Macs, yet you're not distinguishing between them. Also, precisely which Dock 'brand new' doesn't help at all.

Comment: I am distinguishing between the two laptops.  One is described as older, 2012, Retina, Thunderbolt 2, OS X 10.11.6.  The second is described as newer, 2017, USB-C, Big Sur.  I don't distinguish between the OWC docks as the have similar features and work fine on the newer laptop but cause a kernel panic when attached to the Thunderbolt port on the older laptop.  The docks work okay when attached as USB-C docks when attached by USB to the older laptop but that is missing the greater bandwidth Thunderbolt should offer.

Comment: My bad - I misread 10.11.6 as 11.6. I'd be pretty sure still running El Cap will be the issue.

Comment: You are unlikely to root-cause and solve this yourself, as Thunderbolt devices have always exposed latent bugs in macOS and you are likely running into yet-another one of these (which may well have been fixed in a later version of macOS). That being said, whenever you report a panic you should always try to include at least one (preferably all) of the panic reports in your posting. To make them even more useful, first enable kernel symbolication (see, e.g., my footnote at the bottom of my answer in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/426067/macos-crashes-on-any-sound/426093#426093)